# Laravel4 how to upload a chunked file?

Tags: laravel, upload, laravel-4

I'm curious as to whether Laravel 4 has built in functionality to perform file uploads as chunks? Do you know whether it does? And if so could you point me to some documentation regarding it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.

But you can add a library like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). This blog post might be useful, [Chunked Transfer-Encoding in PHP With Guzzle](http://mtdowling.com/blog/2012/01/27/chunked-encoding-in-php-with-guzzle/)